# Neo4J: How to increment property by 1 for each collect

Tags: neo4j

How do you increment a property by 1, starting at 0 for each new collection set?

IF DATA SET WERE:

```
MERGE (node1 {Property: 1})-[rel1:REL]->(nodeA {Property: "A"})
MERGE (node2 {Property: 2})
MERGE (nodeB {Property: "B"})
MERGE (node2)-[rel2:REL]->(nodeA)
MERGE (node2)-[rel3:REL]->(nodeB)
```

WHAT WOULD BE DYNAMIC WAY TO GET:

```
SET rel1.Property=0
SET rel2.Property=0
SET rel3.Property=1
```

SOMETHING LIKE:

```
MATCH (node)-[rel:REL]->()
WITH DISTINCT node, COLLECT(rel) as relcol
FOREACH(r IN relcol | 
   foreach (i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(relcol)-1) | 
       SET (r[i]).Property = (i + 1)   ))
```

Except that gives error:

Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Expected Long(0) to be a org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an extraneous `FOREACH` level; and you should have used `relcol[i]` instead of `r[i]`, and `i` instead of `i + 1`.

This should work better:

```
MATCH (node)-[rel:REL]->()
WITH node, COLLECT(rel) as relcol
FOREACH (i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(relcol)-1) | SET (relcol[i]).Property = i)
```

- `DISTINCT` is not needed for your `WITH` clause, since [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) (like `COLLECT`) automatically treat grouping keys (like `node`) as distinct.
- There is no way in general to predict which of the 2 relationships from `node2` will end up being assigned a `Property` value of `0` or `1`. I assume you don't really care.

Comment: (relcol[i]) I had tried it with one level but could not figure what to place there.  Brilliant! Thanks!